# check_box_tag and params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some checkboxes like so in a form:

```
<%= check_box_tag "marked[#{relative_filepath}]", 1, false %>
```

Which produces:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" style="display: none;" name="marked[/blah]" id="marked__blah">
```

Now supposedly, I should there should be a hash in params[:marked], but this is nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From [`railsapi.com`](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002394):

> "The HTML specification says unchecked
>   check boxes are not successful, and
>   thus web browsers do not send them."

I usually use something like `params[:object][:method].to_bool`.

Comment: Right now the checkboxes are checked via javascript, but even if I remove the *style="display:none;"* and visibly check them and then post the form, params[:marked] is still nil.

Comment: What parameters are being sent? What do you get with `params.inspect`?

Comment: This even though I've checked off some boxes:

`{"authenticity_token"=>"+a7L3q+LMRgEWungZm6TvFkpXuOpsl7jdi+gWu0SFxw=", "_method"=>"delete", "action"=>"delete_folder", "controller"=>"browser"}`